# RibbonX OnAction: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins, ribbonx

I'm using the [RibbonX Visual Designer 2010](https://www.andypope.info/vba/ribboneditor_2010.htm) add-in from Andy Pope to create a custom tab, groups, and buttons.  I already have all kinds of macros as VBA code in an XLAM workbook that will be open on startup.  The problem I have is that I cannot figure out how to call the procedure from any of these buttons.  RibbonX Visual Designer provides a property form for a button with an OnAction field.  I have tried

ProcedureName

"ProcedureName"

"'spreadsheetname.xlam'!ProcedureName"

All I get is an error message "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".
This procedure takes no arguments, so that's not the problem.  The attached image shows what the property form looks like and the OnAction field.

[Property form with OnAction Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtvFI.png)

Can someone give me a clue about the form of the procedure call here?

Comment: Is ProcedureName a public sub in a public module (vs. a private sub behind a worksheet for example)? If not, give it a try.

Comment: I have created a Reference connection to the XLAM file that contains the macros.  I had hoped that would put them in the same namespace.  I suspect I need to specify a specfic module but don't quite know how.

Comment: Did some reading.  Private keyword is not in evidence so modules and subs are public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should have read your question more attentively. The key was *"This procedure takes no arguments"*.

In Ribbon Editor, just provide

```
NumberFormatTwoDecimals
```

for `OnAction`, and also **make sure your sub is declared as follows**:

```
Public Sub NumberFormatTwoDecimals(control As IRibbonControl)
    'Your code goes here...
End Sub
```

Excel expects you to make room for a `control` parameter that it systematically passes to the sub you specify, even if you don't have any use for said parameter.

Developers often specify the same sub in many `OnAction` properties for different controls, because once in their sub, they can check the `ID` and/or the `Tag` property of the `control` parameter to decide what to do:

```
Public Sub MyActionHandler(control As IRibbonControl)
    Select Case control.ID
        Case "MyButton1": HandleMyButton1
        Case "MyButton2": HandleMyButton2
        Case Else: MsgBox "?!?"
    End Select
End Sub
```

With the latter approach, you don't have to modify your existing code base to accomodate the `control` parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer.  Because Ribbon Editor is an addin, I could not look at the code.  After seeing your answer, I looked again at Ribbon Editor and found there is a tab which automatically generates read-only stubs of the necessary callback code.  Thanks for responding.  I was really stuck and now I can see the end of the project from here.  :)

Answer (score 3):

For ribbon buttons the callback should look like the following one:

```
C#: void OnAction(IRibbonControl control)

VBA: Sub OnAction(control As IRibbonControl)

C++: HRESULT OnAction([in] IRibbonControl *pControl)

Visual Basic: Sub OnAction(control As IRibbonControl)
```

You can all callbacks described for all kind of ribbon controls in the following articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)